# Get Data From XML by Livecode

Tags: xml, livecode

I just learn Livecode and try a few tutorials to get data from XML format. I just confuse.

Here are my XML code:

```
<current><city id="1642911" name="London"><coord lon="106.83" lat="-6.17"/><country>Indonesia</country><sun rise="2014-05-29T22:56:30" set="2014-05-30T10:43:59"/></city><temperature value="302.254" min="302.254" max="302.254" unit="kelvin"/><humidity value="76" unit="%"/><pressure value="971.07" unit="hPa"/><wind><speed value="1.24" name="Calm"/><direction value="20.5019" code="NNE" name="North-northeast"/></wind><clouds value="20" name="few clouds"/><precipitation mode="no"/><weather number="801" value="few clouds" icon="02d"/><lastupdate value="2014-05-30T04:50:44"/></current>
```

And here are my Livecode code:

```
<?lc
#get location
put url ("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&mode=xml") into Location

#get lon and lat
put revCreateXMLTree(Location, false, true, false) into locationTree
put revXMLNodeContents(locationTree, "current/city/coord/lat") into latitude
put revXMLNodeContents(locationTree, "current/city/coord/lat") into longitude


#put longitude and latitude information to weather url
put url ("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" & latitude & "&lon=" & longitude & "&mode=html") into weather

put weather
```

The problem is, I don't know how to call the data on XML `(locationTree, "current/city/coord/lat")` which the code is like this `<coord lon="106.83" lat="-6.17"/>`. Could you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get earth data back when I load

```
 http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=0&lon=0&mode=html
```

in the browser.

Could it be that your second `put url` command does not get the right variables loaded and then just loads with latitude and longitude = 0?

Also, make sure to have the right structure for the `revXMLNodeContents`:

```
put revXMLNodeContents(pTree, "preferences/recentDocuments/" & tRecentDocument) & return after tListOfRecentDocuments
```

Your example looks like it does not know which city to load into the LONG and LAT. Can you see it doing the proper thing when stepping trough the code?

Update:
1. Correct Typo for **locationTree** on put RevCreateXMLTree

Comment: Hi, I just have update my question. May you can help me, please.. :)

Comment: Do you know this lesson?    http://lessons.runrev.com/s/lessons/m/4071/l/7011-how-to-read-in-data-from-an-xml-file

Comment: Yes, I know. I learned from that lessons. But, there are no explain for call xml tree with <coord lon="106.83" lat="-6.17"/>. I mean the description is in the bracket.

Comment: hi, Tate83. Thanks for help, finally I've got the solutions.. In that lessons. call attribute with using "put revXMLAttribute(pTree, "preferences/introMessage", "size") into tIntroMessageSize". thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Since 6.5.0 you can use a more compatible version of XPath, using `revDataFromXPathQuery()`. In your script replace `revXMLNodeContents...` with

```
put  "current/city/coord[@lat]" into myXPath
revDataFromXPathQuery(locationTree,myXPath) into myLong
```

Frankly, I haven't tried this yet, but the Release Notes for 6.5 indicate that this should work.

Comment: it shows {file "/var/www/livecode/nana/weather.lc"
  row 12, col 6: Function: error in function handler (revDataFromXPathQuery)
  row 12, col 1: put: error in expression
}

Comment: You already accepted the other answer, so I assume I don't need to look into this anymore.